# Forwarding an error in Swift

Tags: swift, error-handling, try-catch, forward, throw

Is there a better solution to forward a Swift error from one function to another?

In the moment, I'm doing it like this:

```
enum Error:ErrorType{

    case Error1
    case Error2
}

func func1()throws{
     do{
         try func2()

        }catch Error.Error1{
            throw Error.Error1

        }catch Error.Error2{
            throw Error.Error2
        }
}

func func2()throws{
     // proof something
     throw Error.Error1
}
```

So, to forward an error, I need to catch all the errors and throw them again.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: don't wrap it in a do ... catch block.

```
func func2() throws{
     // proof something
     throw Error.Error1
}

func func1()throws{
     try func2()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to catch them they will be thrown automatically as you marked your function with `throws`

```
func func1() throws {
    try func2()
}
```