# rethrows for class/struct instance method in swift error handling

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift2

I am writing a struct that calls a method that can throw an error, however i dont want to handle the error here as i cant do anything at this point, i want to just bubble it up to the caller of me like you can do in java/c#.

E.g writing a Json parser with a nested structure:

```
struct InnerParser {

    let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter

    init( dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter) {
        self.dateFormatter = dateFormatter
    }

    func parse(json: JSON) throws -> Inner  {
        let id = json["id"].string

        guard let actId = id, else {
            throw ParserError.UnexepectedResponse(json)
        }

        return Inner(id: actId)
    }

}
```

This is fine but the problem is here:

```
struct MiddleParser {

    let innerParser: InnerParser

    init(innerParser: InnerParser) {
        self.innerParser = innerParser
    }

    func parse(json: JSON) throws -> Middle {
        let id = json["id"].string
        var inners = [Inner]()
        for (_, innerJson) in json["Inner"] {
            do {
                inners.append(try self.innerParser.parse(innerJson))
            } catch (let error) {
                throw error
            }

        }
        guard let actId = id, where inners.count > 0 else {
            throw ParserError.UnexepectedResponse(json)
        }
        return Middle(id: actId,inners:inners)
    }
}
```

I have to do a 'do catch rethrow ' which seems clunky, is there a way to just do a try and rather than going into a catch it escapes the current function and raises an error on the callee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33350601/1370336, in your "MiddleParser" struct, you don't have to wrap the call in a `do` - `catch` block (since your function is marked with `throws`), just use:

```
inners.append(try self.innerParser.parse(innerJson))
```

Comment: Hmm wierd i tried this initially and it didnt work, must have been a long day