# throwing a thrown error

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

When I don't want to handle an error, and want the error to be passed, is there a better way than catching the error and throwing it again?

```
func myThrowingFunction() throws { 
  do {
    try anotherThrowingFunction()
  } catch(let error) {
     throw error
  }
}
```

In other languages you can just do:

```
func myThrowingFunction() throws { 
  anotherThrowingFunction()
}
```

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33350360/forwarding-an-error-in-swift

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric, I could not find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other languages you can just do:
>
> ```
> func myThrowingFunction() throws { 
>     anotherThrowingFunction()
> }
> ```

And so too in Swift:

```
func myThrowingFunction() throws {
    try anotherThrowingFunction()
}
```